# .Net core SQL cache dependency

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, sqlcachedependency

I am trying to implement caching in ASP.Net core app. Currently What I have implemented is In Memory caching using `IMemoryCache` but what I want is cache should get invalidated if corresponding record in SQL server 2016 gets changed. One way I found it `SQLCacheDependency` but it is not a part of .Net Core as per [this link](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=SqlDependency)

Any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now this class hasn't been migrated to the .Net Core, so you can't easily manage out such logic. Probably it will be a part of .Net Standard 2.0, so you either implement some temporary solution with [`CancellationChangeToken`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory#cache-dependencies) with direct sql database checks (which is very inefficient) or wait for update.

Answer (score -1):

You could add CancellationChangeToken and then call Cancel method on it, this should evict your record from the in-memory cache. On top of it, there is a PostEvictionDelegate callback available to you (to fire additional actions after the cache record has been evicted).
You can read more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory

Comment: How do you suggest to call cancel method? Create a polling for the sql database?

Comment: @VMAtm Well, polling is one way. Considering it's a cache, though, cache should be validated when the database is actually called (based on cache invalidation timeout and so on, unless it's critical to always validate it) - if cache is a miss then the cancel method is called as part of repository implementation.